# How to format uniformly spaced python print statements

Tags: python-3.x, printing

This will likely be a simple question and have a simple answer.  I have a series of Python3 print statements that I would like to look like shown below when printed to the screen.

```
test_integer_to_month ................... OK
test_month_to_integer ................... OK
test_abbreviated_int_to_month ........... OK
test_days_in_month ...................... OK
```

Even though the first set of character strings are not the same length, I want the dots to fill the remaining spaces and the OK, statement to end at the same column.  The code I am using looks like this

```
import sys
passed = '................... OK'
failed = '................... FAILED'

print('{:30s}{}'.format('test_integer_to_month', passed))
print('{:30s}{}'.format('test_month_to_integer', passed))
print('{:30s}{}'.format('test_abbreviated_int_to_month', passed))
print('{:30s}{}'.format('test_days_in_month', passed))
```

However, I get the following output

```
test_integer_to_month         ................... OK
test_month_to_integer         ................... OK
test_abbreviated_int_to_month ................... OK
test_days_in_month            ................... OK
```

Is there a way that I can use a format statement to fill X number of spaces with the `'.'` such that the line starts one space after the descriptive character string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
passed = 'OK'
failed = 'FAILED'
padding = ' ' + '.' * 25

print('{:.40s} {}'.format('test_integer_to_month' + padding, passed))
print('{:.40s} {}'.format('test_month_to_integer' + padding, passed))
print('{:.40s} {}'.format('test_abbreviated_int_to_month' + padding, passed))
print('{:.40s} {}'.format('test_days_in_month' + padding, passed))
```

Padding is single space followed by 25 periods.

The 1st field in the format pattern is set at precision of 40 which
will trim of excess padding.

Outputs:

```
test_integer_to_month .................. OK
test_month_to_integer .................. OK
test_abbreviated_int_to_month .......... OK
test_days_in_month ..................... OK
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the total characters in a single line, then this would do:

```
line_length = 80
passed = ' OK'
failed = ' FAILED'

def get_print_string(msg_to_print, suffix):
    leftover_length = line_length - (len(msg_to_print) + len(suffix))
    if leftover_length > 0:
        msg_to_print = msg_to_print + "." * (leftover_length - 3) + suffix

    return msg_to_print

# Test code
print(get_print_string('test_integer_to_month', passed))
print(get_print_string('test_month_to_integer', passed))
print(get_print_string('test_abbreviated_int_to_month', failed))
print(get_print_string('test_days_in_month', passed))
```